# javascript loop through each value of the button and get the return value of submitted button

Tags: javascript

Here is my buttons with different values.

```
<div id="RAM_BtnGroup" class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example" name='ram'>
    <button type="button" value="8GB" class="btn btn-outline-success">8GB </button>
    <button type="button" value="16GB" class="btn btn-outline-success">16GB </button>
    <button type="button" value="32GB" class="btn btn-outline-success">32GB </button>
    <button type="button" value="64GB" class="btn btn-outline-success">64GB </button>
Price: <span id="totalCost"></span>
```

So when I randomly click on different buttons, I'm still getting back the value of 8GB.

```
 var ram = document.querySelector("button[type=button]");
 ram.addEventListener('click', calculateTotal)
```

So how should I click on different buttons in order to get different values?
Should I get the value of button regards to something like this? But it is not working in this way.

```
var ram = document.querySelector("button[value=8GB][value=16GB][value=32GB][value=64GB]");
```

million thanks to the suggested solution, it's good enough but my calculateTotal function still not counting on the ram.Can you guide me how to fix this out. Here is my code. I am pretty sure that unitcost, additional and qty run smoothly, but after added in ramcost to get the value of ram, it seem to not returning any total price of all items.

```
var ram = document.querySelectorAll('button[type="button"]');

    ram.forEach((ramm) => {
      ramm.addEventListener('click', calculateTotal)
    });
        
    var ram_price = {};
    ram_price['8GB'] = 200;
    ram_price['16GB'] = 300;
    ram_price['32GB'] = 400;
    ram_price['64GB'] = 500;

function calculateTotal
() {
  var ramcost = ram_price[ramm.value];
  var unitCost = product_price[productEl.value];
  var additionalCost = size_price[sizeEl.value] || 0;
  var qty = quantityEl.value || 0;

  totalCostEl.textContent = `Total cost: $${(unitCost + additionalCost + ramcost) * qty}`;
}
```

Comment: I believe you need to use `querySelectorAll()` instead of `querySelector()`

Comment: do you need to catch the value of buttons? (8GB, 16GB etc) ??

Comment: yes i need to catch the value of buttons.

Comment: @MikeS. I think  this doesn't work for me, cause i need to get only submitted button's value instead of returning every value of it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check this difference,

queryselector_class:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_document_queryselector_class

as well as

queryselectorall_class:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_document_queryselectorall_class

I think it will help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to attach the `click` event to every button. `querySelector()` returns only the first matching element, while `querySelectorAll()` returns all matching elements. That's why you need to use the latter:

```js
var ram = document.querySelectorAll("button[type=button]");
ram.forEach((r) => {
  r.addEventListener('click', calculateTotal)
});

function calculateTotal(e) {
  console.log(e.target.value);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" value="8GB" class="btn btn-outline-success">8GB </button>
<button type="button" value="16GB" class="btn btn-outline-success">16GB </button>
<button type="button" value="32GB" class="btn btn-outline-success">32GB </button>
<button type="button" value="64GB" class="btn btn-outline-success">64GB </button>
```

Comment: Hi there, i tried to run the script which combine with my function but i couldn't get the button's value to perform calculation with it. Can you please help to figure out what is the problem as i had edited my question to the latest. Million thanks to your feedback!

Comment: Change your function so that it accepts `e` parameter: `function calculateTotal(e) {` and then define your variable like this: `var ramcost = ram_price[e.target.value];` as I shown in the example

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div id='container'></div>
```

I hope this helps, you can create a class ButtonToPress and then instance buttons. Its working

```js
class ButtonToPress {
  constructor(n) {
    this.n = n;

    const button = document.createElement('button');
    button.onclick = this.print.bind(this);
    button.innerText = this.n

    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(button);
  }

  print() {
    console.log(this.n);
  }
}

let buttons = [];
for (let i = 8; i < 128; i *= 2) {
  buttons[i] = new ButtonToPress(i + 'GB');
  console.log(buttons[i]);
}
```